# C# ActionFilterAttribute what is default AttributeUsage

Tags: c#

Example

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RedirectingActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
```

But if we don't use `AttributeUsage`, what is default value for `ActionFilterAttribute`. I search in google but I can not find it.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it is not, there is just example: [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true)] WHY MINUS THEN?

Comment: I did not downvote your question and even if I did there is no reason to get upset about that. The default values are in the documentation: Go to the __Remarks__ section and click on each of the properties. On each linked page the default value is stated. I am really just trying to help you to find the answer to your question.

Comment: sorry and thank you for helping me, I didn't check Remarks links :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the default value for ActionFilterAttribute

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All,
                   AllowMultiple = false,
                   Inherited = true)]
```